# Count a foreach loop and create new element in php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, foreach

I'm working on a Mega Menu for WooCommerce Product Category. I'm able to get the list of all Subcategories using the code below;

```
$parent_id = 37; //ID of the Parent Category
$subCat_of_parent = get_terms('product_cat',array('child_of' => $parent_id));
```

Then used in a html structure as below;

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
        <?php
        foreach ($subCat_of_parent as $subcat) {
            ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($subcat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $subcat->name; ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
         ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This worked by getting all the list of subcategory of the parent category in this format;

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
           <li><a>1st subcategory</a></li>
           <li><a>2nd subcategory</a></li>
           <li><a>3rd subcategory</a></li>
           <li><a>4th subcategory</a></li>
           <li><a>5th subcategory</a></li>
           <li><a>6th subcategory</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div>
</div>
```

what i want to achieve is after the 3rd subcategory, it should break and continue on a new column, so that i can get something like this;

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
           <li><a>1st subcategory</a></li>
           <li><a>2nd subcategory</a></li>
           <li><a>3rd subcategory</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul>
           <li><a>4th subcategory</a></li>
           <li><a>5th subcategory</a></li>
           <li><a>6th subcategory</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div>
</div>
```

How can i achieve this? Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array_chunk()](https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/array_chunk.php) to divide the array into groups of 3.

```
<div class="row">

<?php

    $chunks = array_chunk($subCat_of_parent, 3);

    foreach ($chunks as $group) {
        print '<div class="col-md-6">';
        print '<ul>';

        foreach ($group as $subcat) {
            print '<li>';
                //to-do
            print '</li>';
        }

        print '</ul>';
        print '</div>';
    }

?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to emit the inner `<div class="col-md-6"><ul>` and the `</ul></div>` part every three categories.

Here is the pseudocode:

- Emit `<div class="row">`
- Set a counter, something like `$i = 0`
- Start your for loop, `foreach ($subCat_of_parent as $subcat) {`
- Now say `if ($i == 0)`, emit the start `div` tag and start `ul` tag.
- Emit your list item
- `$i = ($i + 1) % 3`
- Now say `if ($i == 0)`, emit the close `ul` tag and close `div` tag.

If the number of subcategories is not a multiple of three, you need extra logic at the end to make sure the last group is properly closed off.

Comment: Thanks @Ray for the break down, i was able to make it work following your breakdown

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4,5,6);
        $count = 0;
?>
    <div class="row">
    <?php
        foreach ($subCat_of_parent as $subcat) 
        {
            // echo "count =".$count;
            if($count%3 == 0)
            {
             echo ('<div class="col-md-6">
                <ul>');
            }
            $count++;
    ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($subcat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $subcat->name; ?></a>
            </li>

    <?php
            if($count%3 == 0)
            {
             echo ('
                </ul></div>');
            }

        }
    ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working, You can use this.

```
<?php
$subCat_of_parent = array('1st sub', '2nd sub', '3rd sub', '4th sub', '5 sub', '6 sub', '7 sub');
$subCat_of_parent = array_chunk($subCat_of_parent, 3);
?>
<div class="row">
    <?php
    foreach ($subCat_of_parent as $subcats) {
    ?>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <ul>
            <?php
            foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
                ?>
                <li><a href="#"><?php echo $subcat; ?></a></li>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            </ul>
        </div>        
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Got an error with the code after testing on the <li></li> line (Error: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string) .. I have edited your answer which made it work with no errors